# .net List(Of List(of Object)) Extension

Tags: .net, vb.net, extension-methods

Why does this extension:

```
<Extension()> _
    Public Function GetLastItem(ByVal l As List(Of Object)) As Object
        Return l(l.Count - 1)
    End Function
```

Work for instance of type `List(of Object)` but not for instance of type `List(Of List(Of Object))`?

Object is the most generic type in .net so `List(of Object)` is an `Object` and the extension should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a `List(Of List(Of Object))` isn't an `Object`.

Rewrite your extension like this:\

```
<Extension()>_
Public Function GetLastItem(ByVa l As List(Of T) As T
  Return l(l.Count - 1)
End Function
```

In fact, this is even more general:

```
<Extension()>_
Public Function GetLastItem(ByVa l As IEnumerable(Of T) As T
  Return l.ElementAt(l.Count() - 1)
End Function
```

Of course, you should just use Linq:

```
someListOfThings.Last();
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use your example but i got an error "Type T is not defined"...? I already used template on c++, is it similar?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with VB.NET syntax.  I'm a C# guy.  Nonetheless, you should definitely just use the framework-provided extensions.  Much less work.

Answer (score 7):

No, a `List(Of List(Of Object))` isn't a `List(Of Object)`. You can add a new `Object()` to the latter, but not to the former, for example.

Alternatively, as I like to put it: a bunch of bananas is not the same as a fruit-bowl.

It's not entirely clear why you're writing this anyway though - why not just use the [`Last()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775.aspx) extension method on `IEnumerable(Of T)`? ([That already has an optimization for `IList(Of T)`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/29/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-11-first-single-last-and-the-ordefault-versions.aspx), if that's what you were worried about.)

You *could* make your method generic - ideally targeting `IList(Of T)` rather than just `List(Of T)` - but I'd recommend that you just use `Last()` instead...

Answer (score 1):

> Object is the most generic type in .net so List(of Object) is an Object and the extension should work...?

No.  This would require covariance, which is supported in [IEnumerable(Of Out T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx#Y0) but not `List(Of T)`.  (Note the "Of **Out** T)  For details, see MSDN's page on [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

Note that, in this case, there is already an extension method in LINQ for this: [Enumerable.Last](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function GetLastItem(Of T)(ByVal l As List(Of T)) As T
    Return l(l.Count - 1)
End Function
```

You will not need to specify T when calling it as an extension.